# Creating ImageList object in a loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I have very simple logic for list view items creating. I'm storing all the col headers name from dataGridView into **ColNamesForm1** array and then only comparing if last 5 characters match with **(num)** or **(cat)** string. For these two options I'm appending different picture into listview **lvMoveFrom** using of **Populate** function stored in static classs **OtherFunctions**.

But something is wrong in my code because after last iteration it is appending images from the last column - if the first column is (num) and the last column is (cat) the images in listview are all the same - from cat image.

How can I fix this issue? I was wondering about creating new ImageList object for every columns but I have no idea, how can I do that dynamically, e.g. using of loop index i.

Please, can you help to solve my problem.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ColNamesForm1.Length; i++)
    {
        if (ColNamesForm1[i].ToString().Substring(0, 4).ToUpper() != "COL_" && Regex.IsMatch(ColNamesForm1[i].ToString().Substring(4, 1), @"^\d+$") == false)
        {
            if (ColNamesForm1[i].ToString().Substring(ColNamesForm1[i].ToString().Length - 5) == "(num)")
            {
                OtherFunctions.Populate(lvMoveFrom, ColNamesForm1[i].ToString(), @"C:\pictures\num.png");
            }
            else
            {
                OtherFunctions.Populate(lvMoveFrom, ColNamesForm1[i].ToString(), @"C:\pictures\cat.png");
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void Populate(ListView lv, string itemName, string pathToPicture)
{
    ImageList img = new ImageList();
    img.ImageSize = new Size(30, 30);
    img.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(pathToPicture));
    lv.SmallImageList = img;
    lv.Items.Add(itemName, 0);
}
```

Comment: `ColNamesForm1[i].ToString().Substring(ColNamesForm1[i].ToString().Length - 5) == "(num)"` is equal to `ColNamesForm1[i].ToString().EndsWith("(num)")`

Comment: What type is `ColNamesForm1`

Comment: It will do because you are using the same `ListView` each time you call  `lv.SmallImageList = img;` So the last set of images are going to be the ones that the `lv` uses. You should give each `Item` an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Problem

So basically this:

```
ImageList img = new ImageList();
img.ImageSize = new Size(30, 30);
img.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(pathToPicture));
lv.SmallImageList = img;
lv.Items.Add(itemName, 0);
```

Was adding a new image list to the `ListView`. The same `ListView` you passed it everytime (so you were effectively overwriting it). Secondly, the line:

```
lv.Items.Add(itemName, 0);
```

The second argument is the index in the image list (that you assigned to the `ListView`). So giving it `0` will ask the `ListView` to pick the image from `lv.SmallImageList[0]` (psuedo code) basically.

### The Solution

To remove the overwriting I pulled the image setup logic out of the `Populate` and put it back in the main method. I'll break down just the setup logic:

```
ImageList img = new ImageList();
img.ImageSize = new Size(30, 30);

var paths = new List<string> { @"C:\pictures\num.png", @"C:\pictures\cat.png" };
paths.ForEach(path => img.Images.Add(MediaTypeNames.Image.FromFile(path)));

lvMoveFrom.SmallImageList = img;
```

I put all the image paths into a `List<string>` and just used the `LINQ` `ForEach` to iterate over each one adding it to the `ImageList img`. There is no difference from your original code, apart from I add **all** the images to the `ListView` and I **only do it once**.

So then to make your code easier to understand I did some simple refactorings.

First was invert if statement:

```
if (ColNamesForm1[i].ToString().Substring(0, 4).ToUpper() != "COL_" && Regex.IsMatch(ColNamesForm1[i].ToString().Substring(4, 1), @"^\d+$") == false)
```

To:

```
if (ColNamesForm1[i].ToString().Substring(0, 4).ToUpper() == "COL_"
                || Regex.IsMatch(ColNamesForm1[i].ToString().Substring(4, 1), @"^\d+$"))
{
    continue;
}
```

This is almost like a guard clause, it says if we don't meet these minimum conditions then move to the next item.

Then  I simplified your method execution by reducing duplication:

```
if (ColNamesForm1[i].ToString().Substring(ColNamesForm1[i].ToString().Length - 5) == "(num)")
{
     OtherFunctions.Populate(lvMoveFrom, ColNamesForm1[i].ToString(), @"C:\pictures\num.png");
}
else
{
      OtherFunctions.Populate(lvMoveFrom, ColNamesForm1[i].ToString(), @"C:\pictures\cat.png");
}
```

To:

```
var image = ColNamesForm1[i].ToString().EndsWith("(num)")
                ? 0 // corresponds with the position of the image in the ImageList
                : 1;

OtherFunctions.Populate(lvMoveFrom, ColNamesForm1[i].ToString(), image);
```

Finally you will see that I change your `Populate` method. Firstly we are prepopulating your `ListView` with the images, then using that ternary operator to choose which index of the image to show.

The code all together is:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageList img = new ImageList();
    img.ImageSize = new Size(30, 30);

    var paths = new List<string> { @"C:\pictures\num.png", @"C:\pictures\cat.png" };
    paths.ForEach(path => img.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(path)));

    lvMoveFrom.SmallImageList = img;

    for (int i = 0; i < ColNamesForm1.Length; i++)
    {
        if (ColNamesForm1[i].ToString().Substring(0, 4).ToUpper() == "COL_"
            || Regex.IsMatch(ColNamesForm1[i].ToString().Substring(4, 1), @"^\d+$"))
        {
            continue;
        }

        var image = ColNamesForm1[i].ToString().EndsWith("(num)")
                        ? 0 // corresponds with the position of the image in the ImageList
                        : 1;


        OtherFunctions.Populate(lvMoveFrom, ColNamesForm1[i].ToString(), image);
    }
}

public static void Populate(ListView lv, string itemName, int imageIndex)
{

    lv.Items.Add(itemName, imageIndex);
}
```

Now you can simplify further:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageList img = new ImageList();
    img.ImageSize = new Size(30, 30);

    var paths = new List<string> { @"C:\pictures\num.png", @"C:\pictures\cat.png" };
    paths.ForEach(path => img.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(path)));

    lvMoveFrom.SmallImageList = img;

    for (int i = 0; i < ColNamesForm1.Length; i++)
    {
        if (ColNamesForm1[i].ToString().Substring(0, 4).ToUpper() == "COL_"
            || Regex.IsMatch(ColNamesForm1[i].ToString().Substring(4, 1), @"^\d+$"))
        {
            continue;
        }

        var image = ColNamesForm1[i].ToString().EndsWith("(num)")
                        ? 0 // corresponds with the position of the image in the ImageList
                        : 1;

        lvMoveFrom.Items.Add(ColNamesForm1[i].ToString(), image);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have an issue with part paths.ForEach(path => img.Images.Add(MediaTypeNames.Image.FromFile(path))); 'System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image' does not contain a definition for 'FromFile'

How can I handle it?

Comment: I've simply replaced the previous one by paths.ForEach(path => img.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(path)));

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution is really great, appreciate your time.